# Understanding Magento layout xml file (reference, block, ...)

Tags: magento, layout, block

I have a some questions about the layout xml file which is placed in  app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout.

On some tutorial, it had this structure:

```
<layout>
    <adminhtml_example_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="awesome/adminhtml_example" name="example" />
         </reference>
    </adminhtml_example_index>

    <adminhtml_example_edit>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="awesome/adminhtml_example_edit" name="example_edit" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_example_edit>
</layout>
```

Can someone please explain what those lines mean? The tutorial can be found here: [here](http://codemagento.com/2011/02/grids-and-forms-in-the-admin-panel/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

The XML based structure of **Magento** seems bit confusing and annoying at the beginning but its well-known that eventually strong capability and customizability…

```
<adminhtml_example_index></adminhtml_example_index>
```

This tag refers to the **[router]*[controller]*[action]**
The router is the uniquely identified name for a particular dispatch. From the example you’ve given, under the admin tag of the ***config.xml*** file, we can find the router name `adminhtml`.

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <awesome before="Mage_Adminhtml">Super_Awesome_Adminhtml</awesome>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Under that router are the module settings related to this router.

So if the url contains **/admin/example/[index]**, magento will find the correct router which is `<adminhtml>` then will find the controller named `example` and find the correct action which is in this case `index` *(/admin/example/ will be dispatched to the default index action)*

```
<adminhtml_example_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="awesome/adminhtml_example" name="example" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_example_index>
```

In the layout file, for **router controller action** combinations, layout updates are defined. In here the update will be applied to the main block named as `content` which holds the page content section.

`<block>` tag is used to define the block we need to refer. `<type>` tag is important. It refers to the correct block class that should be used when rendering this layout *(Remember in Magento’s MVC structure the View consists of both Block classes and phtml files)*

In `awesome/adminhtml_example` here, `awesome` is the block configuration name mentioned in **config.xml** file. `adminhtml_example` is the block class to be used.

See

```
<global>
    -----
    <blocks>
        <awesome>
            <class>Super_Awesome_Block</class>
        </awesome>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

Under the `block` tag, a unique block name is defined *(good naming convention will preserve the uniqueness)*. Then the class path for these block can be identified as `Super/Awsome/Block/`.

Block configuration name is now resolved. `adminhtml_example` is the exact block class to be used. Any underscore after block name *(awesome)* will be converted to directory separator.

According to that, the full path of the block class will be

```
[codepool]/Super/Awsome/Block/Adminhtml/Example.php
```

The class name will be like

```
class Super_Awesome_Block_Adminhtml_Example extends ….
```

If we have the layout file we can specify it here.. then that `.phtml` file will be rendered using the above block class

```
<reference name="root">
    <block type="page/html" name="root" template="simplepage.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Hope this helps.. Sorry if anything is unclear…

Comment: The explanation is superb. Keep it up. :)

Answer (score 5):

layout handlers are mapped to MVC controller so expect your handler

`<adminhtml_example_index>` to be used in adminhtml/example/index controller page

and

`<reference name="content">` means that the blocks or other references inside those blocks will be available in `content` block on your theme templates

for further reading i suggest :

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base
- http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/no-frills-magento-layout