# How Magento parses XML layout code, Where are the files that parses layout XML

Tags: xml, magento, layout, xml-parsing, magento-1.7

I want to know how **Magento parses the XML layout codes**. Where are the parser files, I dont have idea how it is done. can anyone please share anything useful?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about parser files. But layout xml explanation can be found in here.. Check if it suits you..
[Understanding Magento layout xml file (reference, block, ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092716/understanding-magento-layout-xml-file-reference-block/14880664#14880664)